# Elasticsearch how to match a two-dimensional array?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a special data structure. For example:

```
{
 "name": "test",
 "age": 20,
 "gender": "M",
 "custom": [
     ["tel", "1234567"], ["weibo", "abcde"], ["weixin", "abcdefg"]......
 ]
}

{
 "name": "test1",
 "age": 30,
 "gender": "F",
 "custom": [
     ["电话", "1234567"], ["微博", "abcde"], ["微信", "abcdefg"]......
 ]
}
```

The custom filed is a two-dimensional array, I want to search `["tel", "1234567"]`. How to make it possible by ES?

Comment: Can you change how your `custom` array is defined? The problem with this two-dimensional array, is that ES will flatten it out during analysis, so that `custom` will contain the tokens `tel`, `1234567`, `weibo`, `abcde`, etc, i.e. the 2D structure is lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the way you index your `custom` array. The problem is that ES will flatten it out during analysis, so that `custom` will contain the tokens `tel`, `1234567`, `weibo`, `abcde`, etc, i.e. the 2D structure is lost.

If you want to be able to query `tel` and `1234566`, you need to define your `custom` field as a [`nested` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), similar to this.

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "gender": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "custom": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can index your documents like this:

```
PUT index/type/1
{
 "name": "test",
 "age": 20,
 "gender": "M",
 "custom": [
     {"key": "tel", "value": "1234567"}, 
     {"key": "weibo", "value": "abcde"},
     {"key": "weixin", "value": "abcdefg"}
 ]
}
```

Finally, you can query "tel 1234567" and get the documents you expect with the following query:

```
POST index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "custom",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "custom.key": "tel"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "custom.value": "1234567"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a try. You’ve really been a big help!

Comment: Cool, let us know how it goes.

Comment: I have a new question, Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199531/how-to-match-email-or-telephone-by-elasticsearch