# How to fuzzy match email or telephone by Elasticsearch?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I want to make fuzzy match for email or telephone by Elasticsearch. For example:

match all emails end with `@gmail.com`

or

match all telephone startwith `136`.

I know I can use wildcard,

```
{
 "query": {
    "wildcard" : {
      "email": "*gmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

but the performance is very poor. I tried to use regexp:

```
{"query": {"regexp": {"email": {"value": "*163\.com*"} } } }
```

But doesn't work.

Is there better way to make it?

> curl -XGET localhost:9200/user_data

```
{
    "user_data": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "user_data": {
                "properties": {
                    "address": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "age": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "comment": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "created_on": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                    "custom": {
                        "properties": {
                            "key": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "gender": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "qq": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "tel": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "updated_on": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1458832279465",
                "uuid": "Fbmthc3lR0ya51zCnWidYg",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "version": {
                    "created": "1070299"
                }
            }
        },
        "warmers": {}
    }
}
```

the mapping:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "index_phone_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [ "digit_only" ],
          "tokenizer": "digit_edge_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [ "trim" ]
        },
        "search_phone_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [ "digit_only" ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [ "trim" ]
        },
        "index_email_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [ "lowercase", "name_ngram_filter", "trim" ]
        },
        "search_email_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [ "lowercase", "trim" ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "digit_only": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\\D+",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "digit_edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "15",
          "token_chars": [ "digit" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "name_ngram_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "20"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "user_data" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "analyzer" : "ik"
        },
        "age" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "gender": {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "qq" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "email" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "analyzer": "index_email_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "search_email_analyzer"
        },
        "tel" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "analyzer": "index_phone_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "search_phone_analyzer"
        },
        "address" : {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer" : "ik"
        },
        "comment" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "analyzer" : "ik"
        },
        "created_on" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "updated_on" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "custom": {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "key" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "value" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to create a custom analyzer which makes use of the [n-gram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) for emails (=> see below `index_email_analyzer` and `search_email_analyzer` + `email_url_analyzer` for exact email matching) and [edge-ngram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) for phones (=> see below `index_phone_analyzer` and `search_phone_analyzer`).

The full index definition is available below.

```
PUT myindex
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "email_url_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [ "trim" ]
        },
        "index_phone_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [ "digit_only" ],
          "tokenizer": "digit_edge_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [ "trim" ]
        },
        "search_phone_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [ "digit_only" ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [ "trim" ]
        },
        "index_email_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [ "lowercase", "name_ngram_filter", "trim" ]
        },
        "search_email_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [ "lowercase", "trim" ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "digit_only": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\\D+",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "digit_edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": "1",
          "max_gram": "15",
          "token_chars": [ "digit" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "name_ngram_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": "1",
          "max_gram": "20"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "index_email_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "search_email_analyzer"
        },
        "phone": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "index_phone_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "search_phone_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, let's dissect it one bit after another.

For the `phone` field, the idea is to index phone values with `index_phone_analyzer`, which uses an edge-ngram tokenizer in order to index all prefixes of the phone number. So if your phone number is `1362435647`, the following tokens will be produced: `1`, `13`, `136`, `1362`, `13624`, `136243`, `1362435`, `13624356`, `13624356`, `136243564`, `1362435647`.

Then when searching we use another analyzer `search_phone_analyzer` which will simply take the input number (e.g. `136`) and match it against the `phone` field using a simple `match` or `term` query:

```
POST myindex
{ 
    "query": {
        "term": 
            { "phone": "136" }
    }
}
```

For the `email` field, we proceed in a similar way, in that we index the email values with the `index_email_analyzer`, which uses an ngram token filter, which will produce all possible tokens of varying length (between 1 and 20 chars) that can be taken from the email value. For instance: `john@gmail.com` will be tokenized to `j`, `jo`, `joh`, ..., `gmail.com`, ..., `john@gmail.com`.

Then when searching, we'll use another analyzer called `search_email_analyzer` which will take the input and try to match it against the indexed tokens.

```
POST myindex
{ 
    "query": {
        "term": 
            { "email": "@gmail.com" }
    }
}
```

The `email_url_analyzer` analyzer is not used in this example but I've included it just in case you need to match on the exact email value.

Comment: WoW!  It is amazing!

Comment: You can tune the n-gram min/max parameters, but this setup supports a lot of search cases.

Comment: Depends on many factors (hardware, amount of data, etc), which is why you have to try it out and tune for your needs. I just showed you one way that works, now you need to pave it to your liking :)

Comment: You probably need to wipe your index and data and rebuild it from scratch. Then explain what query you're sending.

Comment: If i search "136", all the document will be match. Should I change the min_gram?

Comment: Please explain how you search? can you show a phone number that matches and which shouldn't?

Comment: `{"query": {"term":{"tel": "123"}}}` I want to show all include 123 telephone, doesn't want to get 1, 2, 12, 13, 23. And I found the `_source` doesn't have `email` field.

Comment: Your query looks wrong... there's no `tel` query. And the way it looks like, you haven't setup your index correctly.

Comment: Still, I'm not sure your index is set up correctly. It looks like the search term is also ngramed, which it shouldn't. Please update your question with what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`

Comment: Yes, you didn't install it correctly, it appears, since there are not analyzers in the settings. Just simply run `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/user_data -d '{ the whole JSON}'`. Make sure to delete the index first.

Comment: Found a error `nested: MapperParsingException[Analyzer [ik] not found for field [address]];`

Comment: It's your name field which has an analyzer called `ik` which is not defined. Clean it up.

Comment: no errors found, but `ik` is a chinese analyzer, I need it.

Comment: ok, but you need to declare it somehow in the settings... otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your patient! I want to give your bounty reputation next time!

Comment: Thanks a lot! everything is ok!

Comment: when I search `163.com` , nothing is return, but I can search `163` or `com`, why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107298/discussion-between-pangpang-and-val).

Comment: I am not using `email_url_analyzer `