# Sql's LIKE search alternative in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have a requirement of searching a number string like "234" from a given field contains values like "abc:+123456789".
This is more as SQL's LIKE search.

I tried following options with around 3 billion documents indexed:

1- Wildcards:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/ccp/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "from": 0,"size": 10,   
  "query": {
      "wildcard": {
       "original_address": {
          "value": "*6421685922*"
       }
    }
   }   
}'
```

This is taking around 600 sec which is too much.

2- query-string

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/ccp/_search?pretty' -d '{ 
   "query": {"filtered": {"query": { "query_string": {
          "fields": [ "original_address" ],
          "query": "*7570850706*"
        }
      }      
    }
  }
}'
```

Still taking too much time.

What is the best alternative of same in elastic queryDSL or CURL?

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199531/how-to-fuzzy-match-email-or-telephone-by-elasticsearch/36200119#36200119

Comment: @ Val - Thanks for the reply.. I will try this for sure. I have read the complete thread.. it goes to chat . Did that work for him? how was the performance for him?

Comment: Yes, he said "Thanks a lot! everything is ok!" ;-) Try it out!

Comment: Great.. Let me try it.. will update you. Thanks again :)

Comment: note that you'll probably need to use an `ngram` tokenizer instead of `edgeNGram` since you also want to match on tokens inside the numbers.