# Elasticsearch partial matching of a number field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to partially match a number field. In the query below, I'd like id (which is defined as a long) to match any document which starts with 419. (so 4191 should match, as should 419534 but not 123419)

```
{
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": [{
        "customerName": "asc"
    }],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "term": {
                            "id": 419
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone got a neat solution to use in my query?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199531/how-to-fuzzy-match-email-or-telephone-by-elasticsearch/36200119#36200119 but you might need to store your `id` as a string instead.

Comment: Converting it to a string would be easy but I had hoped someone knew of a better / different solution. Breaking up the numbers in parts (e.g 1 12 123) seems like a convoluted way to search for numbers too. I'll work on converting it to a string and leave this open for a bit to see if any solutions roll in. Thanks again for the help man, you're wicked.

Comment: Out of the blue, can you try to use a `query_string` instead and use `419*` as the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a egde ngram, you could declare a not analyzed text sub field in your id mapping :

```
"mappings": {
    "default": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "fields": {
                    "prefixed": {
                        "type":  "string",
                        "index":    "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

and use a [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) against that field:

```
"query": {
    "prefix" : { 
        "id.prefixed" :  { "value" : 419 } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed what I ended up doing and it seems to be the only way to achieve this at the moment. I will accept the answer because it's the same solution Val provided and I initially thought of. If a better answer comes along I'll accept that one instead.

Answer (score -2):

in a string field you can use wildcard query:

```
{
"query" : {
    "wildcard" : { "id" : "*419*" }
}
}
```