# Query Match For Integer Number In Elastic Search With Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I followed this article for connecting laravel and ElasticSearch:
https://madewithlove.be/how-to-integrate-your-laravel-app-with-elasticsearch/

I have a table in MySQL database that it has tree field:"title","description" and "price". "title" and "description is string type. so I write below code for searching and this worked correctly:

```
private function searchOnElasticsearch(string $query): array
{
    $instance = new Article;

    $items = $this->search->search([
        'index' => $instance->getSearchIndex(),
        'type' => $instance->getSearchType(),
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'multi_match' => [
                    'fields' => ['title', 'description'],
                    'query' => $query,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);

    return $items;
}
```

But now, I need to check "price" field that is a **bigInt type** like two other field: `'fields' => ['title', 'description','price'],`

**UPDATE**

When I add "price" to field I get this error in laravel:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed
>   to create query: {\n \"multi_match\" : {\n \"query\" : \"bad\",\n
>   \"fields\" : [\n \"description^1.0\",\n \"price^1.0\",\n
>   \"tags^1.0\",\n \"title^1.0\"\n ],\n \"type\" : \"best_fields\",\n
>   \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n \"slop\" : 0,\n \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n
>   \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n
>   \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n
>   \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n
>   }\n}","index_uuid":"mm787GxMS4WjjjqwRD5YIw","index":"commodities"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
>   shards
>   failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"commodities","node":"JYWiIdbLQtu3aWkm_F-e9Q","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed
>   to create query: {\n \"multi_match\" : {\n \"query\" : \"bad\",\n
>   \"fields\" : [\n \"description^1.0\",\n \"price^1.0\",\n
>   \"tags^1.0\",\n \"title^1.0\"\n ],\n \"type\" : \"best_fields\",\n
>   \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n \"slop\" : 0,\n \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n
>   \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n
>   \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n
>   \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n \"boost\" : 1.0\n
>   }\n}","index_uuid":"mm787GxMS4WjjjqwRD5YIw","index":"commodities","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For
>   input string: \"bad\""}}}]},"status":400}

Comment: And what happens when you add the `price` field to your query?

Comment: Please add the full error to your post, it's more legible than in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest something like this, i.e. split the query into two parts, one for text fields and another for numeric fields. However, only add the match on numeric fields if the `$query` is indeed a number:

```
$body = [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'should' => [
                [
                   'multi_match' => [
                       'fields' => ['title', 'description'],
                       'query' => $query
                   ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

// if the query is numeric add an additional clause for the price field
if (is_numeric($query)) {
    $body['query']['bool']['should'][] = [ 'match' => [ 'price' => $query]];
}

$items = $this->search->search([
    'index' => $instance->getSearchIndex(),
    'type' => $instance->getSearchType(),
    'body' => $body
]);
```

Comment: thank you for trying, I change my code. but I get same error... when I comment 'match' part program run. that shows error come from this part... In addition,I changed "must" to "should"

Comment: Doh, you're right, what about adding some logic that would only add the price match if `$query` is a number? That's probably the only way to make it work.

Comment: please more explain to me and If you can get me a code. I found this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714512/elasticsearch-partial-matching-of-a-number-field) but I can not convert to laravel collection format. please look to this link and if you can convert ,post your answer. thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer correct. I accept and vote up your answer