# Is character @ special in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We are searching Elasticsearch from .NET Core 2 project using Nest library, with this query:

```
var response = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(
        s => s.Query(q =>
                q.QueryString(qs => qs
                    .DefaultField(f => f.Info)
                    .Query(term)
                    .DefaultOperator(Operator.And)
                )));
```

If Elasticsearch contains Document with Info `myemail@gmail.com` and `term=myemail` or `term=gmail`, Document is found.

Problem is when searching `term=myemail@gmail`, since Document is not found in that case. Why is character @ making problem? Should it be somehow escaped?

Comment: Your `info` field is probably an analyzed string (i.e. has `text` type). Try changing it to type `keyword` and it will work as you expect

Comment: Keyword fields are only searchable by their exact value. I would like to search by substrings. I would like to enable user to find document in these cases: `term=my`, `term=email`, `term=email@gmail` and so on. Any typed substring should be enough to match.

Comment: This answer should help then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199531/how-to-fuzzy-match-email-or-telephone-by-elasticsearch/36200119#36200119

Comment: @Uros, take a look at analyzing the field that contains emails with an analyzer that includes `uax_url_email` tokenizer - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html