# Elastic search query string issue while searching

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on elastic search and now I have an array of phone numbers which I want to search from elastic search but I don't know that where I am doing mistake in my written code below is my working code

```
contacts = ["+966","+965"];

    let getPhoneSearchUsers = function (login_user,contacts:any) {

        if(_.size(contacts)>0){
            return {
                "_source": ["id", "username", "full_name","phone"],
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "prefix": { "phone":contacts }
                            }
                        ],
                        "must_not" : [
                            {
                                "ids": {"values": [login_user]}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I always receive following exception

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "json_parse_exception",
        "reason": "Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@3520c9; line: 8, column: 35]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "json_parse_exception",
    "reason": "Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@3520c9; line: 8, column: 35]"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

can anyone let me know that where I am doing mistake in my code?

Comment: `contacts` is an array and you're enclosing it in another array. Besides, the `prefix` query only accepts a string and not an array. Here is another solution that would probably work better for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199531/how-to-fuzzy-match-email-or-telephone-by-elasticsearch/36200119#36200119

Comment: @Val afetr implementing this code

{
  "_source": ["id","username","phone"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { 
            "prefix": {
                "phone": ["92321","92321"]
            }
        }
      ],"must_not": [
        {
          "ids": {"values": ["116"]}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Val then stil found another exception like below

then exception {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 8:26"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_state_exception",
    "reason": "Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 8:26"
  },
  "status": 500
}

Comment: Re-read the second sentence of my comment