# Elasticseatch exact match or partial match

Tags: elasticsearch, search

My idea is to create exact / partial match. So, If exact match is found in any of the fields, return only it. If no exact match, return all partial matches. To Illustrate, I will give example on emails.
I use **standart analyzer** and map emails as **text**.

To give an example, we have following emails indexed:

1. one@gmail.com
2. two@gmail.com
3. three@gmail.com
4. four@hotmail.com

If query string is "one@gmail.com" only one@gmail.com should be returned.

If query string is "gmail.com" all gmail emails should be returned.

I currently have to queries:

```
{"query": {
   "multi_match":{
      "query":"one@gmail.com",
      "fields":["email", "other_fileds"],
      "type":"phrase"
}
```

This one will find exact matches when standart analyzer and text mapping is used.

```
{"query": {
    "query_string":{
       "query":"gmail.com",
}
```

This one will find all partial matches.

I need to somehow combine them with OR.

---

So far I followed suggestion from the comment and do the following:
Firstly, i search using phrase matching

```
{"query": 
   {"query_string":
      {
         "query":"one@gmail.com",
         "type":"phrase"
      }
   } 
}
```

If there are NO hits, I do a second search:

```
{"query": 
       {"query_string":
          {
             "query":"one@gmail.com",
          }
       } 
    }
```

This tends to work well in the majority of cases. But it fails the following case, when search query contains a lot of data from different fields. For example "one@gmail.com Alex 095111111".

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199531/how-to-fuzzy-match-email-or-telephone-by-elasticsearch/36200119#36200119

Comment: you can prioritize query in elasticsearch, something like "if else" does not exist. You need two queries and to coordinate them in your application.