# Wildcard search issue with long datatype in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

```
   {
   "from":0,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "query_string":{
                  "query":"10*",
                  "lenient":true,
                  "fields":[
                     "phoneNumber"
                  ],
                  "escape":true
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here the **phonenumber** is of type long and we want to perform wildcard search on it.
I am passing the query as **10***  ( `"query":"10*",`)
Actual hits should have been 15 but I am getting 0 hits.

If I am doing the same for a field with type keyword(string) **Address**, with the query `"query":"newyork*",` I am getting the result.

Does anyone have any idea why we didn't get the hits for fields with type long?

Comment: Here is a solution for searching on phone numbers but you'll need to store them as text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36200119/4604579

Answer (score 2):

**It's not directly possible to perform wildcards on numeric data types. It is better to convert those integers to strings.**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "phoneNumber": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "phoneNumber": "101"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "10*",
            "fields": [
              "phoneNumber"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65109764",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "phoneNumber": "101"
        }
      }
    ]
```

If you want to do a partial match, then you can even go with [edge n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

Comment: @Avinash Kalol did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @AvinashKalol glad this worked for you  Can you please upvote and accept the answer as well . You can accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark beside my answer