# elasticsearch match query in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have follow query with terms, that works fine.

```
{
  "query": {
   "terms": {
          "130": [
            "jon@domain.com",
            "mat@domain.com"
          ]
        }
  }
}
```

Found 2 docs.

but now i would like to build similar query with match (want to find all users in domain). I've tried follow query without any result

```
{
  "query": {
   "match": {
          "130": {
            "query":"@domain.com"
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Found 0 docs. Why??

Field 130 has follow mapping:

```
"130":{"type":"text","analyzer":"whitespace","fielddata":true}
```

Comment: Please add the mapping of index.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant please take a look my update

Comment: Here is a solution that allows you to match anything in an email address: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36200119/4604579

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a whitespace analyzer, then the token generated will be :

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "jon@domain.com",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

So [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) will match with the above token as it returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field, but match query will give 0 results

Instead, you should use a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) (which is the default one), which will generate the following tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "jon",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "domain.com",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**You can even go through the [uax_url_email tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html#analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer) which is like the standard tokenizer except that it recognizes URLs and email addresses as single tokens.**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
 {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "130": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "130":"jon@domain.com"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "130": {
        "query": "@domain.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65121147",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "130": "jon@domain.com"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Just note that the `@` is not matched actually, as it is removed by the standard analyzer.

Comment: Yes @Val, I just mentioned about uax_url_email tokenizer, which OP can use according to his use case :)

Comment: @Ilya did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @llya it's been a long time. I hope you are doing well  Did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 